# Easier way to aggregate a collection of memory accesses made by a Windows process?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, x86, operating-system

I'm doing this as a personal project, I want to make a visualizer for this data.  but the first step is getting the data. 
My current plan is to

1. make my program debug the target process  step through it
2. each step record the EIP from every thread's context within the target process
3. construct the memory address the instruction uses from the context and store it.

Is there an easier or built in way to do this?

Comment: If there is, I am not aware of it. However, your proposed method here is likely to be too slow for it to be practically useful for non-trivial applications. Each step will require a context switch between the client and the debugger, and even trivial programs execute a _lot_ of instructions. Also, it's hard to see the usefulness of such a hypothetical memory access map, once constructed - the same memory will often be reused for different purposes during the life of a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Intel PIN for dynamic binary instrumentation / running a hook for every load / store instruction.  [intel-pin](/questions/tagged/intel-pin)

Instead of actually single-stepping in a debugger (extremely slow), it does binary-to-binary JIT to add calls to your hooks.

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/81205/Pin/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the best way to do this is probably instrumentation like Peter suggested, depending on your goals. Have you ever ran a script that stepped through code in a debugger? Even automated it's incredibly slow. The only other alternative I see is page faults, which would also be incredibly slow but should still be faster than single step. Basically you make every page not in the currently executing section inaccessible. Any RW access outside of executing code will trigger an exception where you can log details and handle it. Of course this has a lot of flaws -- you can't detect RW in the current page, it's still going to be slow, it can get complicated such as handling page execution transfers, multiple threads, etc. The final possible solution I have would be to have a timer interrupt that checks RW access for each page. This would be incredibly fast and, although it would provide no specific addresses, it would give you an aggregate of pages written to and read from. I'm actually not entirely sure off the top of my head if Windows exposes that information already and I'm also not sure if there's a reliable way to guarantee your timers would get hit before the kernel clears those bits.